# Creating new instance of concrete implementation in interface - is this an antipattern?

Tags: java, interface, dao, design-principles

Let's say I have the interface `AuthorDao` with two different implementation classes for example `MyAuthorDaoImpl1` and `MyAuthorDaoImpl2`.

In my interface `AuthorDao` I have some basic crud methods and **one extra method which is `static`** for getting a new instance of `MyAuthorDaoImpl1`.

It looks like this:

```
public interface AuthorDao {

    void methodA();
    void methodB();
    ...
   
    static MyAuthorDaoImpl getInstance() {
        return new MyAuthorDaoImpl1();
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is this static method `getInstance()` is not an anti-pattern?
   Because in my opinion we shouldn't depend our interface on concrete
   implementation class, but my friend says it's okay, and he is pretty sure, that this should be work like this. He says it is **factory method**.
2. He says we can create instances of this interface by constructor, we don't have to use this `static` method, therefore this is nothing bad. Is it true, that this is nothing bad? I think it is example of **tight coupling** and interface should not depend on concrete implementation, but he says this is not the case.
3. He refers that this is the same case like in `Calendar` class, because there is also `getInstance()` method.

---

**Edit**

Also, in his opinion this static method will simplify refactoring if we will decide to change `MyAuthorDaoImpl1` to `MyAuthorDaoImpl2`.
Because the only change will be in `getInstance()` method.

Comment: NO that is not a factory pattern.  GOOD that you question this.

The purpose of an interface is to be a contract.  The contract can have static methods, but in my opinion they should not be generating instances of the interface implementations...

Comment: Regarding the Calender class, it is an abstract class.  An abstract class can have methods which generate implementations of x (interface).

You are on the right path to becoming a good developer.

Comment: @SusanMustafa I think it's good that you mention that as being your opinion. Nothing is ever that clear-cut. `List.of`, `Set.of`, etc. are good examples to add to the mentioned `Calendar` instance. And to add yet another opinion, I think that as long as the resulting API does not make the contract's client depend on specific implementations, this is fine. (I'm guessing the `Collections` class would not have existed if static interface methods came at a good time). And the only code smell with the `getInstance()` method is that it takes no input, which implies there is "the" 1 implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This implementation is a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency), which roughly looks like:

[image: circular dependency]

While it will likely work in Java, imagine what would happen if you no longer included the class `MyAuthorDaoImpl` when later you decided to implement `ABetterAuthorDaoImpl`.  Now you have to change the interface.  It is a minor change in this case, but imagine it on a larger scale.

Normally a factory method returns the interface type rather than the implementation type.  Example:

```
class AuthorDaoFactory {

    static AuthorDao getInstance() {
        return new MyAuthorDaoImpl1();
    }
}
```

This avoids the circular dependency, demonstrated by this diagram:

[image]

You'll note that there is no circular path in the dependencies.  This may not matter for this simple example, but what if your factory method created an instance of a class that was dynamically loaded based on a config?  This is a common example of [Inversion of Control (IoC)](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/inversion-of-control) and is often used to do things like provide a common interface to different hardware.  The implementation is hidden behind the interface.

You'll notice that the Java `Calendar` class method `getInstance` returns the type `Calendar`.  The underlying implementation may be locale-specific.  If you look at the description of the method in the Java documentation it says:

> Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale. The Calendar returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the default locale.

What is the implementation then?  You don't know and don't care, you only know it is of type `Calendar`.